# Save as process fails in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, internet-explorer-10

I an using Internet Explorer to view and render reports and they work.  I then press the `Save` button and select any of the options and a new tab opens and nothing. I don't get a word document, excel, pdf, csv...nothing...just a blank tab.  Any suggestions?  It works from Chrome but I really need it to work from IE.

Update:
I have noticed that when the new tab opens in IE there is no `&rs:Command=Render` at the end of the URL like there is in Chrome.

Comment: Are you running IE in compatibility mode? I think later versions of IE need to be in compatibility mode for older versions of SSRS.

Comment: I have tried all the different compatibility modes and it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the process to use a URL with the Format=PDF included and that allows IE to open/save the file as I expect.